# Where does paket save it's global cache in the Window's WSL

Tags: f#, windows-subsystem-for-linux, f#-interactive, paket

Where does paket save it's global cache ?

Specifically in the Window's WSL  (Ubuntu 18.4 in my case).

I found that generate-load-scripts, generates

```
namespace PaketLoadScripts

#r "C:\\Users\\MyName\\.nuget\\packages\\fsharp.data\\3.3.2\\lib\\netstandard2.0\\FSharp.Data.dll"
```

Is there a way to configure that location ?
Shouldn't it be loaded from `~/.nuget/packages` ?

EDIT: 
Must be a bug , because in Windows Git Bash Shell

```
me@MyPc MINGW64 /c/code/@me/
$ uname -a
MINGW64_NT-10.0-18362 DESKTOP-4P6REML 3.0.7-338.x86_64 2019-11-21 23:07 UTC x86_64 Msys
```

It works fine

```ml
namespace PaketLoadScripts

#r "../../../packages/System.Data.SQLite.Core/lib/netstandard2.0/System.Data.SQLite.dll"
```

Comment: This would be WSL1, right (so no insider build)? If you use `which dotnet` in your WSL Bash what is the output you get? Is it the `dotnet` executable installed on the 'Windows side of things' or the one you installed in your WSL (the Linux executable)? Usually if you use `storage: none` in your `paket.dependencies` file the packages can be found in your `~/.nuget/packages/` folder - otherwise they should be in the packages folder in your project (same level as the `paket.dependencies` file. Is that the case?

Comment: `which dotnet` , didn't check that. didn't think of it , good one.
And yes, using `storage: pakages` solves the problem